# Laravel event is not broadcasting on production server

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel-websockets package for some real-time features. I am using redis as queue connection. I have an event `TestUpdated` which I am broadcasting on `test.{id}` private channel. **The event gets fired and caught by the client properly when I am on a local machine. But on production server, I get `BroadcastException` thrown:**

> Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException in /home/forge/mydomain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php:117

Horizon dashboard also exposes the event data:

```
{
event: {
test: {
class: "App\Test",
id: 1,
relations: [
],
connection: "mysql"
},
socket: null
},
connection: null,
queue: null,
chainConnection: null,
chainQueue: null,
delay: null,
chained: [
]
}
```

Fragment of my `websockets.php` config file:

```
'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'enable_client_messages' => true,
        'enable_statistics' => false,
    ],
],
```

My observations:

- Pusher gets connected. authEndpoint hits properly. I
- Presence channel works.
- The noticable difference between local machine and production is that on production the scheme is `https`

I am using an arbitrary pusher app id, key and secret (someId, someKey and someSecret'). My client-side config:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    authEndpoint: 'my/endpoint',
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'someKey',
    wsHost: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? window.location.hostname : 'mydomain.com',
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    encrypted: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development' ? false : true
});
```

Config from broadcasting.php:

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'encrypted' => true,
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => 6001,
            'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME')
        ],
    ],
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: try changing broadcasting.php file host key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same issue:

I changed host to the production URL:

Here is the updated config:

```
'pusher' => [
    'driver' => 'pusher',
    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'encrypted' => true,
        'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST'),
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME')
    ],
],
```

And in the `.env` file:

```
PUSHER_HOST=example.com
```

Remember to exclude `http/https` from the host. It's not `https://example.com`, it's `example.com`.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm not very experienced with Pusher. On local it is working so fine, but on production server broadcasting not working. Tried your solution but no luck.

Comment: @Mycodingproject Have you solved the problem?